How can I turn a MOSFET on and off with a PNP transistor?
I need to control a MOSFET (a Jiangshu JieJie JMSL0302AU) with an ATtiny1616 to turn a 40 A load on and off (without switching.) Could you please check if this schematic is correct? The ATtiny will be running at 2.5V, but the MOSFET's VGS(th) is 4V.
The intention is for the MOSFET to turn on when the ATtiny pin is high and turn off when the pin is low.
Q1 is one half of an onsemi BC847B dual PNP.


That circuit will not work as drawn. The BJT is the wrong type and connected upside down. 2.5V is pretty low but for a small enough load, you could probably find a logic level MOSFET or just use a NPN.

If you can change the control parity of the ATtiny pin to low is ON and high is OFF, then changing Q1 from a PNP to an NPN will work.

As vir mentions, if your load current is not too high, a MOSFET such as AO3400A has less than 50mΩ of Rds(on) with 2.5V drive.

Does “without switching” mean without using a mechanical switch or does it mean not switching out the parts for different parts or…maybe something else?

(@CarlRutschow parity make that polarity.)

onsemi BC847B is not dual PNP, it contains one PNP and one NPN.

I assume your reasoning for pulling the gate up to 8V is to reduce the FET Rds(on) for the FET you’ve chosen. Fair enough, we'll do that here too. You could also consider a logic-level FET as well.
At any rate, what you show won't work. Q1 will never turn on. You could replace it with an NPN and have an active-low logic control, but it will use current all the time when the FET is off (this would be the default state with GPIO at high-Z.)
Instead, move the PNP to the high side, and control it with an additional NPN. This gives both the level shifting for the FET gate, and it has active-high control.
As follows (simulate it here):

The circuit draws practically zero standby current, and very little current for the pre-driver when on. The default state will be everything off.
MORE:
The GPIO-to-base resistor can be a high value due to the combined gain (10,000) of the NPN-PNP pair, which cuts GPIO current to a minimum. The NPN base 10k pull-down resistor is recommended to prevent false turn-on while the ATtiny starts up and gets around to programming the GPIO.

I'd be afraid of leaving the NPN base unconnected. Even nano-amps of NPN base current can switch on the PNP.

The switch is there only for illustrative purposes, to show the behavior with a high-Z GPIO. Normally it will be driven to a solid high or low.  That said, a pulldown wouldn’t hurt.

I have no idea about prices and availability, but wouldn't an example with a logic level FET enhance your answer? (I'm aware that the OP did not specify any load requirements.)

@hacktastical Most MCUs boot with all GPIO set to inputs, and it takes a few clock cycles before your code can change the one in use to an output. I wouldn't be surprised if an input-mode GPIO could leak a few nanoamps into the base of that NPN, or even the NPN itself get enough collector-to-base leakage to turn itself slightly on. I never like using BJTs without a pulldown, especially not in high-gain applications like this.

Revised the sim to add a pull-down.

Thank you all for your answers.
The current in the load is 40A and I plane to use JMSL0302AU-13 as Mosfet https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2201121830_Jiangsu-JieJie-Microelectronics-JMSL0302AU-13_C2938488.pdf
And for NPN-PNP I want to use BC847BPDXV6T1G https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1810301515_onsemi-BC847BPDXV6T1G_C152304.pdf

The transistor type isn't critical. You can use the common general-purpose types 2N3904 NPN and 2N3906 PNP.

The simpler option is to just use a low-drive-voltage MOSFET and drive its gate directly. The DMG3414 comes to mind, with a rated maximum Rdson of only 29 mΩ at 2.5 V on the gate. It has an input capacitance of about 900, which isn't that much, but as I don't know what you're doing with it: if you need lower input capacitance and don't need that much current, the SSM3K56 might be an option; much higher Rdson (300 mΩ at 2.5 V), but only 55 pF of input capacitance.
Of course, if you have to drive tens of amps of load current, neither of these will work--there are some high current logic-level FETs like the DMN1004 or the SiR178, but I'll stop here--I can't give suggestions for every possible load condition.
You'll definitely want a pull-down resistor from gate to source; you probably don't want the gate floating while the MCU is still starting up.

This is probably even a cheaper solution than adding more transistors to act as a driver for your present FET; all the MOSFETs I've listed above cost less than US$0.55 in single quantity from Digikey, except the extremely-high-current SiR178, which is $1.67.

Edit: Now that you've clarified your requirements, many of the above devices won't work. The DMN1004 still would, but would require impractically good heatsinking (it's rated for 55 A at 2.5 V drive, but that's only if you can keep its case temperature at 25 °C, which is unrealistic). The only suitable FET of the options I gave above would be the SiR178, which doesn't specify current ratings at any specific gate voltage but would probably be fine to handle upwards of 50 A with sufficient heatsinking (going by its power rating at Tₐ=70 °C and its maximum Rdson at 2.5 Vgs)--and it wouldn't need as excessive a heatsink as the DMN1004 would.
There are, of course, other options as well. Take a look through your favorite distributor's catalog, and filter out any FETs that don't specify any characteristics at Vgs = 2.5 V or below.

"The current in the load is 40A and I plan to use JMSL0302AU-13 as MOSFET"
Since you have a relatively beefy MOSFET with ~20nC of gate charge and a heavy load, I think it would be better to drive the gate smartly so as to minimize the switching stress and losses.
This has the reverse logic to what you are requesting:

Here is the same circuit with an inverter transistor. You can see the losses during switching (red trace, peaking at 80W):

Alternatively, if you are not switching frequently, this will work, however the time to turn off is around 600ns due to the storage time of the BJTs:


You've drawn Q1 upside-down. That obscures the fact that it will still work as-if it was a PNP transistor normal-side-up, except with a low current gain (usually between 1/4 and 4):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When the input is driven, Q1 acts like an emitter follower, and outputs a voltage about one diode drop (0.7V) higher. When SW1 is open, Q1 is switched off, and the output is pulled up by R2. The logic table is below. The levels it produces are not usable to drive the N-MOS load switch gate.



In
Out




open
8.0V


0V
0.7V


2.5V
3.2V



The intended operation would be:



In
Out




0V
0.0V


2.5V
8.0V


open
don’t care



We can do it with PNPs only:

simulate this circuit
Q1 buffers the input signal. Q2 and Q3 are a current mirror. Q4 is an inverter and gate driver.
Of course, insisting on using PNPs only complicates things. But you wanted to use PNPs, so PNPs you got :)
